# Javascript - what is the purpose of wrapping functions or codes in a function?

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

This probably is not a new question, but where is the purpose of wrapping a function or codes inside `((function () {...})());`? for instance,

```
//Self-evoking anonymous functions
((function () {

    alert("hi");

})());
```

What's the difference with no wrap,

```
alert("hi");
```

I still get the same result - `hi`

What can you pass/ put in the brackets in the end bit - `})());`? and why?

Comment: Read this http://blog.nitishkumarsingh.com/javascript-anonymous-functions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a function creates a scope. You can have params inside and do more than just alerting.
Now you can do the same without a function, but then you will keep the state on the window object and thats something that you would like to prevent in some cases.